# Encoding a String data structure from video frame to Unicode in Python

Tags: python, string, opencv, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to convert a large string data structure (a video frame captured from OpenCV).

Below is where I'm getting camera frame data (a data string), and then encoding it as unicode utf-8 data:

`frame = camera.get_frame()
frame_data = unicode(frame, "utf-8")`

I'm currently getting an error of

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' code can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Am I correct in assuming this is something possible to do? If so, how would I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I ended up changing the code in `camera.get_frame()` from

```
retval, image = self.image.read()
data = cv.imencode('.jpg', image)[1]tostring()
```

to

```
retval, image = self.image.read()
retval, buffer = cv.imencode('.jpg', image)
jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode('.jpg', image)
```